# creating an array from doubly linked list indexes positions

Tags: java

I have a problem with one of our old exam tasks.
the task is 
"the method positions should return a field containing exactly the positions of those elements of the list that have null as content. if there are no such elements than return a field with the length 0"

the code starts with :

```
public int[] positions() {
    int[] result = new int[0];
```

I keep getting stuck on because of the "new int[0]" when I tried solving the problem without it I managed to get somewhat of a result. but I don't know how to do it with this part.

Comment: what is the problem with the code exactly? It just creates an empty array. in the rest of the method you should work on the task and reassign the array in case you found `null` values

Comment: I think this is initialized as an array of length 0 because it is the default value that gets returned if no `null` elements were found.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you must return a class data member, because they say "field".

Comment: @MCEmperor I think he/she got confused on that part.

Answer (score 0):

Just think for a moment what the code is doing here.

```
int[] result = new int[0];
```

creates an empty, fixed lenght, primitive array. This array cannot be further expanded.

Your exam task would be translated as (simplifying at a large degree):

```
public int[] positions(final Object[] objects) {
   // Initialize the array with the max possible size, which is the input array size
   final int[] positions = new int[objects.lenght];
   int j = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      if (objects[i] == null) {
         // Assign the index of the null value to the holder array.
         // Increment j, which is the index of the first free position in the holder array
         positions[j++] = i;
      }
   }

   // This will return a copy of the "positions" array, truncated at size j
   return Array.copyOf(positions, j);
}
```

Comment: that is clearly the wrong answer! the code just starts with the default return value in case there i no `null``value. *" if there are no such elements than return a field with the length 0"*

Comment: @AKSW the copyOf method will do the trick. If there are no null values, j will be zero.

Comment: Oh, yes - I overlooked the `j` param. But given that this is the method stub of the exam, I'm sure the idea was to reassign the array in case you found some `null`value. Not sure if he understands the code, but well - it works and solves the task

Comment: @AKSW obviously this is not the most optimal solution. I wanted to keep it simple so he/she can understand, I hope.